# Sending invitation with iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-invite, applinks

I'm trying to send out invites with Facebook SDK, this is my code:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] 
                             initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/835518356527517"]];

[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

I've added the url scheme of fb123456789 (my game id) to the plist and did all the configuration the SDK requires.

The problem is after receiving the invite it sends the user to the AppStore even if the app is installed on the device. How can I make the receiver open the app straight up? instead of sending to the AppStore all the time?

Thanks

Comment: In the fb.me url you posted, you've listed milkthecow://invite as the custom url for your app. Did you add "milkthecow" as a url scheme in your plist as well? That's what Facebook uses to detect if your app is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Ming Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647528/ming-li) you are my hero

so I just had to read some more on Deep Linking/Applinks. I used [facebook's Create App Link](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) tool to re-create the link, then the default fb scheme in the plist file started working. the new applink is fb12345:// the same scheme the plist contains and all is singing and dancing

thanks again!